# Get Last Records for Multiple Items in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple table that stores daily high temperatures for various cities. The table contains 3 fields: `city_id`, `date`, `high_temp`. (Unique is combo of city_id and date)

I'm looking for an efficient query for SQL Server that will allow me to pull the 3 most recent highs for each city. Thus, the result would include every city id listed 3 times.

What is extra challenging (for me at least) is that the high temps are not recorded every day for every city so I can't filter by (`getdate()-1`, `getdate()-2`, etc)

Is there a way to do this without a loop function? Much appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL 2005 and later use [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
WITH temps as
(
  SELECT city_id, date, high_temp,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY city_id ORDER BY date DESC) RowNum
  FROM TemperatureHistory  <-- use the real table name here
)
SELECT city_id, date, high_temp FROM temps WHERE RowNum <= 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table T1
WHERE T1.date IN 
 (SELECT TOP 3 date
  FROM table T2
  WHERE T1.city_id = T2.city_id
  ORDER BY T2.date DESC)
```

Comment: I don't know if this is any faster than D Stanley's answer. But it's more readable to me, since I'm not as familiar with SQL Server as he is.